# sending request to a servlet from remote HTML

Tags: servlets

Is it possible to send a request to a java servlet from a html file that is not in the project?

That is, is this possible

```
<form action="http://example.com/Myapp/savedetails.do" method="post">
// other fields
</form>
```

from a remote html file.

**Note:** i am trying to send a html formatted mail, and allow the users to fill forms through email and submit it in the email itself..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't *call* a Java servlet.

A `Servlet` is a class which a Servlet container uses to handle requests.

Your HTTP client, a browser, serializes a form and sends an HTTP request to whatever is specified in the form's `action` attribute. The Servlet container receives this request, uses the Servlet to handle it, and sends back an HTTP response.

So your browser is simply sending a request. If you specify a URL for a server which is listening and can respond for that request, then you will get a response. The client has no knowledge that a Servlet actually handled it.

What do you think would happen if you did this

```
<form action="http://www.google.com" method="post">
// other fields
</form>
```

Can you not send a request to google because google isn't in your project? What you specify in `action` is just a URL.

Comment: May be i was wrong with phrasing the question right.. apologies..  i have rephrased my question.. all i wanted to know is if it is possible to send such request from a remote html file to a container.. And thanks a ton.. :)

Comment: @BlackPanther Sure. In the same way you can type an address in a browser address bar and click 'send', you can add a URL in a form and click submit (or use javascript). A servlet is just what backs the HTTP server.

Comment: i am trying to send a html formatted mail, and allow the users to fill forms through email and submit it in the email itself.. would this be possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, provided there are no restrictions to make such request. For example try this link its to make search for `Black Panther` with given search engines:

[Google Search](http://www.google.co.in/search?q=Black%20Panther)

Also consider the request method being used at the server end, for example the above link won't work with `'POST'` method.

Comment: k.. it was a dumb question from my part.. but nevertheless, your answer was helpful.. thank u.. :)